# Disable form.item 1 if form.item 2 is filled in

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to hide  `form.item 1` if `form.item 2` is filled in and the other way around.
I want to do it for the following code but i cant find the solution to this.

```
<Form.Item label="Url">
  {getFieldDecorator('url')(<Input/>)}
</Form.Item>
<Form.Item label="Standaard Urls" >
  {getFieldDecorator('url_id', {})(this.getSelectUrls())}
</Form.Item>
```

Basically i want too know how i can hide 1 `form.item` and the rest i can do myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`onFieldsChange`](https://ant.design/components/form/#Formcreate(options)) of `Form.create`, that keeps your `Form` uncontrollable which is the cleanest way.

Wrap your `Form` with a state, pass it and use `onFieldsChange` like so:

```
const FormContainer = () => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);

  const onFieldsChange = (_, changedFiels) => {
    const { password } = changedFiels;
    if (password) {
      console.log(`Now changing ${password.name}`);
      setIsVisible(false);
    }
  };

  const ValidatedFields = Form.create({ onFieldsChange })(MyForm);

  return <ValidatedFields isVisible={isVisible} />;
};
```

> **Warning:** You need to figure how you want to "remove" the form field, it depends on if you need its state or not, for this you can use `display` CSS property:

```
// Will unmount the item and lose it state
{ isVisible && <Form.Item>...}

// Will keep the state and hide the item
<Form.Item style={{ display: isVisible ? 'auto' : 'none' }}>...
```

---

#### Full code:

In this example, you can write in the password field and it will hide other forms items:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Input, Form, Icon } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';

const FormContainer = () => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);

  const onFieldsChange = (_, changedFiels) => {
    const { password } = changedFiels;
    if (password) {
      console.log(`Now changing ${password.name}`);
      setIsVisible(false);
    }
  };

  const ValidatedFields = Form.create({ onFieldsChange })(MyForm);

  return <ValidatedFields isVisible={isVisible} />;
};

const MyForm = ({ form, isVisible }) => {
  const { getFieldDecorator, validateFields } = form;

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="login-form">
      {isVisible && (
        <Form.Item>
          {getFieldDecorator('username', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }]
          })(
            <Input
              prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
              placeholder="Item 1"
            />
          )}
        </Form.Item>
      )}
      <Form.Item style={{ display: isVisible ? 'auto' : 'none' }}>
        {getFieldDecorator('username2', {
          rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }]
        })(
          <Input
            prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
            placeholder="Item 2"
          />
        )}
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item>
        {getFieldDecorator('password', {
          rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }]
        })(
          <Input
            prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
            type="password"
            placeholder="Type here to hide other forms"
          />
        )}
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<FormContainer />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: Edit Q-58305124-HideFormItem]

Answer (score -1):

```
const [showItem1, setShowItem1] = useState(true);
const [showItem2, setShowItem2] = useState(true);

onKeyPress = {() => {setShowItem1(true); setShowItem1(false); }}
onKeyPress = {() => {setShowItem1(false); setShowItem1(true); }}

{
    showItem1 &&
    <Form.Item label="Url">
        {getFieldDecorator('url')(<Input/>)}
    </Form.Item>
}

{
    showItem2 &&
    <Form.Item label="Standaard Urls" >
        {getFieldDecorator('url_id', {})(this.getSelectUrls())}
    </Form.Item>
}
```

Comment: It just won't work, refer to docs https://ant.design/components/form/ for how to render a `Form`.